# Average of Rows Based On Another Columns Values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like this. I'm looking for a clean way in SQL to create a new column with the average between the Column 2 values for the rows where Column 1 equals 1 and 2 for each id.

I have some ideas on gross ways to do this, but I am looking for a straightforward solution since this seems like it should not be too difficult.

| ID | Column 1 | Column 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 100 |
| 1 | 2 | 75 |
| 1 | 3 | 50 |
| 2 | 1 | 45 |
| 2 | 2 | 90 |
| 2 | 3 | 60 |

Comment: You should add a table with the output you expect. Also, some people here like to see some proof of work before attempting to help, i.e., failed attempts at solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use window function `avg` with filtering.

```sql
select *, 
    avg(column2) 
        filter (where column1 in (1,2)) 
        over (partition by id) as avrg
from the_table;
```

| id | column1 | column2 | avrg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 100 | 87.50 |
| 1 | 2 | 75 | 87.50 |
| 1 | 3 | 50 | 87.50 |
| 2 | 1 | 45 | 67.50 |
| 2 | 2 | 90 | 67.50 |
| 2 | 3 | 60 | 67.50 |

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qH2pbHqXXdajp3Xhdz7QFU/1)